# Cannot return null for non-nullable field - Typegoose and TypeGraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I have this Album model set up using Typegoose and TypeGraphQL, which contains multiple songs from the `Song` model using the `AlbumSong` ObjectType:

```js
import {
  prop as Property,
  getModelForClass,
  modelOptions,
  Ref,
} from "@typegoose/typegoose";
import { Field, ObjectType, ID } from "type-graphql";
import { AlbumCategory, } from "./albumCategory.model";
import { Song } from "./song.model";

@ObjectType()
export class AlbumSong {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @Property({ required: true })
  id!: string;

  @Field(() => Song)
  @Property({ type: () => Song, ref: () => Song, required: true })
  song!: Song;
}

@ObjectType({ description: "The Album Model" })
@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { collection: "albums", timestamps: true } })
export class Album {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: () => String })
  title: string;

  @Field(() => [AlbumSong])
  @Property({ type: AlbumSong })
  albumSongs!: Partial<AlbumSong>[];


  @Field()
  @Property({ required: true, default: Date.now })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Field()
  @Property({ required: true, default: Date.now })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
export const AlbumModel = getModelForClass(Album);
```

When trying to query the album using:

```js
@Query((_returns) => Album, { nullable: false, name: "album" })
async getAlbumById(@Arg("id") id: string) {
  return await AlbumModel.findById({ _id: id });
}
```

With the following GraphQL:

```
query Album($albumId: String!) {
  album(id: $albumId) {
    id
    albumSongs {
      id
      song {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get: `"Cannot return null for non-nullable field AlbumSong.song."`

To me it seems like the reference is not working, when i only query the albumSong's `id` it returns just fine...

Comment: As a note `type: () => Song, ref: () => Song` is not valid, when using references `ref` refers to the class / modelname where `type` refers to the reference type (the type of `_id` the referenced class has), by default being `ObjectId`. Also where does this error come from, graphql or mongoose?

Comment: I guess you've to setup a `FieldResolver` to resolve the `song` within an `AlbumSong`. In that case don't expose it as a regular `Field` as this will conflict with the `FieldResolver`. (p.s.: also setup `Dataloader`, to solve the N+1 problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a [FieldResolver](https://typegraphql.com/docs/resolvers.html#field-resolvers) to resolve the song within an AlbumSong

```js
@Resolver(() => AlbumSong)
export class AlbumSongFieldResolver {
  @FieldResolver(() => Song)
  async song(@Root() parent: AlbumSong): Promise<Song> {
    return Song.findOne(parent.song);
  }
}
```